# Is there any statistical data about the film names mentioned in quesions and answers?

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be awesome to see a list of the top 100 frequently mentioned movies on Movies&Tv

Does it exist somewhere?
Can we make it?

Comment: Probably correlates to the most popular tags, honestly. Number one media tag is for *Game of Thrones* followed by *Breaking Bad* and then *Star Wars*.

Answer (score 2):

As @Catija rightly put in the comments, the popularity of a movie on the site is directly correlated with the volume of posts (questions) tagged by the tag of that movie.

So, maybe you can write a script for getting the top tags, and filter out the non-movie tags like `plot-explanation`, etc; and you are left with the dataset you wanted.

Comment: It might already help to just look at the already popularity-sorted [list of tags](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tags).